# insert module to kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, ipcop

I installed latest version of IPCOP, I've the correct module of my wireless card (htc_9271.fw): put it to

```
/lib/firmware/
```

there is not any insmod/rmmod but only modprobe:

```
modprobe htc_9271
FATAL: Module htc_9271 not found.
```

Comment: you can solve your problem with "depmod -a"

Comment: WARNING: Can't read module /lib/firmware/atheros/htc_9271.fw: Exec format error
FATAL: grab_module() failed for module /lib/firmware/atheros/htc_9271.fw

Comment: htc_9271.fw isn't a module but a firmware file

Comment: The corresponding module appears to be `ath9k_htc` so that's what you should modprobe